# SharePoint 2010 Listview save event

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, splist, spview

I am trying to catch the save event on listviews, not the list itself. This is so that i can stop saving of certain views.

I have tried List SPListEventReciever, but this seems to only catch events on the list itself, not the views.

EDIT: As mentioned in comment below, the views im trying to stop people saving are the default views on external lists.

Comment: Can you give more details of what kind of views you want to prevent? The short answer is no, there's no such event you can intercept, but if you give us more details we might be able to come up with an alternative solution.

Comment: The specific views is the default view (public) on external lists that are marked as to be on quick launch. 
All evidence so far points to it not being possible, but thought i might give SO a chance before i give up.

Comment: Oh, so you want people to be able to create their own views, but not alter the existing, default view?

Comment: bingo! pretty much we want to have the default views as templates, and let users create their own public views to share

Comment: Do the users need to be able to modify the lists (add/remove columns etc.)? If not... I think if you remove this permission they can still create _personal_ views. Then you could create a custom action that lets them select a personal view, and then under elevated privileges it creates a copy of that view that is public, not personal. Would that do?

Comment: Sounds like a possible solution, I do see a scenario where we get alot of public views in the end, since as soon as you have created the public copy the user cant remove it again.
If I create an action that changes the view to public, you think i could create an action that can change the view back to private. I guess i would only have to check if the current user is the owner of the view?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't just change the view back and forwards, you'd have to create code that would duplicate the view (and delete the original?). You could use similar code to take the view back to private again. You'd need to keep track of who "owned" which view in e.g. a hidden list somewhere.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback! Im gonna see if I get time to try and implement it later today. 

Feel free to add it an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, I'd try the following:

- Remove regular users' permission to modify lists at all (if this is acceptable). This should still let them create *personal* views.
- Write code that will take a personal view, analyse it, (delete it?) and (using elevated privileges) create an equivalent public view. (You can't just change the `PersonalView` property, sadly.) Be careful to capture everything a user can do on the create-a-view UI - this will be the trickiest part.

  - Optionally write similar code to allow a view to be switched from public back to personal (checking it's not the default view or any other view you're trying to protect.)
  - Optionally keep track of who "owns" one of these custom views, for example in a hidden list, and only allow the owner to take a view back to personal.
- Write an interface to this code, e.g. an application page allowing a user to select from the relevant views, or a custom action on the ribbon.